# Anzograph SPARQL issue

Tags: sparql, anzograph

I have the following SPARQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM {

          ?measurement a  oboe-core:Measurement ;
                          oboe-core:ofCharacteristic oboe-core:Name ;
                          oboe-core:usesStandard :Anaee-franceExperimentalSiteNamingStandard ;
                          oboe-core:hasValue ?anaeeSiteNameStandard .
    
           BIND ( IRI( CONCAT( "http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology" , 
                               ?anaeeSiteNameStandard )  ) AS ?site ) .

           OPTIONAL { ?site rdfs:label ?_anaeeSiteName . }       
    
           BIND ( IF (BOUND (?_anaeeSiteName), ?_anaeeSiteName, "NULL_anaeeSiteName"@en ) AS 
                  ?anaeeSiteName) .

           FILTER (lang( ?anaeeSiteName ) = "en") .

} limit 3
```

**?_anaeeSiteName** is empty knowing that my graph contains :

```
<http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology#Guyaflux> 
rdfs:label "Guyaflux"@en .
```

When I use directly

```
BIND ( IRI( "http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology#Guyaflux" ) AS ?site ) .
```

Instead of `BIND IRI CONCAT`

```
BIND ( IRI( CONCAT( "http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology" , 
            ?anaeeSiteNameStandard )  ) AS ?site ) .
```

I get some results.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thank's

Comment: The above Sparql request works perfectly with Blazegraph

Comment: you should contact the Anzograph devs if it works on other triple stores and you think it's a bug.

Comment: also, `SELECT * FROM {` is invalid SPARQL syntax. This should not work on any triple store ...

Comment: Check that `?anaeeSiteNameStandard` is "#Guyaflux" (or did you mean to add a `#` to the CONCAT string?)

Answer (score 1):

We agree with Uninformed and Andy that we think there are syntax errors. You are missing the graph uri for the FROM and the WHERE key word, and the # in the concat is needed to match your example URI.

Disclaimer: I work for Cambridge Semantics Inc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I removed the "FROM " in order to simplify the query.

The complete Sparql query is below :

```
SELECT * FROM <foret> WHERE {

      ?measurement a  oboe-core:Measurement ;
                      oboe-core:ofCharacteristic oboe-core:Name ;
                      oboe-core:usesStandard :Anaee-franceExperimentalSiteNamingStandard ;
                      oboe-core:hasValue ?anaeeSiteNameStandard .
    
       BIND ( IRI( CONCAT( "http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology" , 
                           ?anaeeSiteNameStandard )  ) AS ?site ) .

       OPTIONAL { ?site rdfs:label ?_anaeeSiteName . }       
    
       BIND ( IF (BOUND (?_anaeeSiteName), ?_anaeeSiteName, "NULL_anaeeSiteName"@en ) AS 
                  ?anaeeSiteName) .

       FILTER (lang( ?anaeeSiteName ) = "en") .

} limit 3
```

The stange think is that when I add the :

```
BIND ( str(?anaeeSiteNameStandard) AS ?anaeeSiteNameStandard ) .
```

just before :

```
BIND ( IRI( CONCAT( "http://www.anaee-france.fr/ontology/anaee-france_ontology" , 
                               ?anaeeSiteNameStandard )  ) AS ?site ) .
```

I get the expected result !